# Restore deleted dataset in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

we have deleted some dataset and now we want them(deleted before 24 hours). so i check the documentation and followed the steps,

```
1. reacreate dataset with same name
2. bq cp mydataset.mytable@ -3600000 mydataset.newtable
```

i also recreated table schema in db and then tried above.
but its giving me error that dataset is not present in my region.

I tried with select,

```
SELECT * FROM `mydataset.mytable`  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 48 HOUR);
```

but no luck.
can anyone help here. what am I missing ?
is there any time bound for this restoration if we deleted dataset ? (like for table we can go back 7 days)

Note: for deletion we followed below steps:

1. drop command to drop table
2. once all tables dropped then we deleted dataset

Answer (score 4):

You can restore the tables from deleted dataset after recreating it with the same name. However, you have to know tables names.

```bash
# 1) Delete the dataset
bq rm -r -f -d TEST_DATASET

# 2) Create a new dataset for restore
bq mk -d --location=us-east4 TEST_DATASET_RESTORED

# 3) Recreate the origin dataset with the same name
bq mk -d --location=us-east4 aw-sndbx-dataplatform-01:TEST_DATASET

# 4) Restore the table from the latest snapshot (alias @0)
bq cp TEST_DATASET.test_table@0 TEST_DATASET_RESTORED.test_table
```

Answer (score 1):

> [Deleting a dataset is permanent and cannot be undone. After you delete
> a dataset, it cannot be recovered or restored](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#deleting_datasets:%7E:text=tables%20and%20views.-,Caution,-%3A%20Deleting%20a).

BigQuery allows you to [recover deleted tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-undelete-table). If you are within the dataset's [`Time Travel Window`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel) you can restore tables, see more at the next [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-datasets#restore_deleted_datasets).